# attaching a contextmenustrip into checkboxlist dynamicly

Tags: c#, checkedlistbox, contextmenustrip

i am trying to attach a built context menu strip into an object which i insert into my CheckBoxList
what i am trying to do is to attach the contextMenuStrip into the new checkbox that is being created inside my checkboxList so when i press on the right click of the mouse the menu will appear
for example :

```
 CheckedListBox cbllist = new CheckedListBox ();
 cbllist.add(object);
```

now inside my list i have a new checkbox that contains my object
how do i attach the contextMenuStrip to it?

thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okey the contextmenu strip should be on the all checkedlistbox and each time i remove an object from the list there is a need to put null inside the cbllist.contextmenustrip
each time an object is being selected the contextmenu strip should be inserted to the cbllist.contextmenustrip